# unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, hardware, pyserial

I receive the error in the following line:

```
 command = input("please type command.example open 1")
        #call the serial_connection() function
        ser.write(b"%d\r\n"%command)
```

Essentially I want the input written by the user and parse it into ser.write, without asking for the input and directly putting the string into `ser.write` such as:

```
ser.write(b'close1\r\n')
```

worked fine, the problem only occurred when i try to use the result of the input as a string to include in ser.write

A bit more of the code:

```
ser = 0

#Initialize Serial Port
def serial_connection():
    COMPORT = int(input("Please enter the port number: "))
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.baudrate = 38400 #Suggested rate in Southco documentation, both locks and program must be at same rate
    ser.port = COMPORT - 1 #counter for port name starts at 0

    #check to see if port is open or closed
    if not ser.isOpen():
        print ('The Port %d is open - Will attempt to close lock 1 Stephan: '%COMPORT + ser.portstr)
        #timeout in seconds
        ser.timeout = 10
        ser.open()
        command = input("please type command.example open 1")
        #call the serial_connection() function
        ser.write(b"%d\r\n"%command)

    else:
        print ('The Port %d is **open** Stephan' %COMPORT)
```

for any clarification, kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try decoding byte string first (if its not a constant string, otherwise just start with  normal string), then applying the format, and then encoding it back?

Also, you should use `%s` instead of `%d` because your` command is a direct input from user, which is a string.

Exmaple -

```
ser.write(("%s\r\n"%command).encode())
```

If you do not pass any arguments , it defaults to current system default encoding, you can also specify an encoding to use such as `utf-8` or `ascii` , etc. Example of that - `ser.write(("%s\r\n"%command).encode('utf-8'))` or `ser.write(("%s\r\n"%command).encode('ascii'))`

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. with that i get the following error:   ser.write(("%d\r\n"%command).encode())
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: If its str, use - %s. Updating in answer.

Comment: glad I could be of help

Answer (score 1):

The left hand argument to % should be a string, but you have passed b"%d\r\n" which is a byte literal.

Suggest replacement with

```
ser.write(("%d\r\n" % command).encode("ascii"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 you should use the string format function:

```
ser.write(b"{0}\r\n".format(command))
```

This works for bytes in Python 3.5 (see [link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-March/133621.html)).

Comment: For Python 3.4 you might consider using the string join function `b", ".join([b'1', b'2', b'3'])`

Comment: thanks for that suggestion, i unfortunatly receive the following error:ser.write(b"{0}\r\n".format(command))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: Yep -- you are correct. As PySerial will only take byte input and Python 3.4 uses Unicode default for strings you'll have to encode to ASCII.