# Unsupported operand types for &: 'str' and 'bytes' in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
if(msg.topic == "abc" & msg.payload == b'1'):
     print("Loop entered")


TypeEror: unsupported operand types for &: 'str' and 'bytes'
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: use `and` instead of `&`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213086/unsupported-operand-types-for-bytes-and-str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and` is how we write conjunctions in Python, so:

```
if msg.topic == "abc" and msg.payload == b'1':
```